# Cut Mod_Security ID with sed/awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, mod-security2

I would like to cut the numbers between the quotas of a Mod_sec ID: [id "31231"]. Generally it is not difficult at all but when I am trying to extract all IDs from multiple reports such as:

```
[Wed Oct 19 15:31:33.460342 2016] [:error] [pid 16526] [client 67.22.202.121] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 400 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/mod_security2.conf"] [line "4968"] [id "000784"] [hostname "example.org"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "WAfYJU1ol@MAAECO@HQAAAAI"]

[Wed Mar 19 15:31:33.460342 2016] [:error] [pid 16526] [client 67.22.202.121] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 400 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/mod_security2.conf"] [line "4968"] [id "9"] [hostname "example.org"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "WAfYJU1ol@MAAECO@HQAAAAI"]

[Wed Mar 19 15:31:33.460342 2016] [:error] [pid 16526] [client 67.22.202.121] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 400 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/mod_security2.conf"] [line "4968"] [id "00263"] [hostname "example.org"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "WAfYJU1ol@MAAECO@HQAAAAI"]
```

I have attempted several commands such as:

```
cat asd | awk '/\[id\ "/,/"]/{print}'
cat asd | sed -n '/[id "/,/"]/p'
```

and many others but they do not print the required IDs but rather include additional output since the pattern is being matched several times. Generally I am able to do something like:

`cat asd | egrep -o "\"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\""` and then cut the output again but this does not work in cases where the ID does not contain 6 numbers.

I am not familiar with all options of awk,sed and egrep and do not seem to find a solution.

What I would like to be printed from above history is:

`000784`

`9`

`00263`

Could someone please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `grep` if `pcre` option is available:

```
$ grep -oP 'id "\K\d+' asd 
000784
9
00263
```

- `id "\K` positive lookbehind to match `id "`, not part of output
- `\d+` the digits following `id "`

With `sed`

```
$ sed -nE 's/.*id "([0-9]+).*/\1/p' asd 
000784
9
00263
```

- `.*id "` match up to `id "`
- `([0-9]+)` capture group to save digits needed
- `.*` rest of line
- `\1` entire line replaced only with required string

Comment: Thank you so much Sundeep, both the sed and the grep solutions are working perfectly. I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now. Thank you for your fast response and explanation as well !!!

Comment: @AngelAsenov glad it helped... you can check out documentation on these topics on SO for examples if you are interested... for example: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/topics and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics

Comment: The provided topics appear to provide very useful information indeed. Thank you so much mate.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*\[id "\([^"]*\)"].*/\1/p'
```

- you need to consume all items before `[id` and after your token
- you need to escape the square bracket

Comment: Thank you so much Jean, this sed solution works flawlessly. I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ids are accessible in the 6th `awk` field when double quotes are used as custom separators:

```
$ awk -F '"|"' '{print $6}' file
000784
9
00263
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I was not aware you could print a string between chosen separators by using the | delimiter. This appears to be very useful.